# Why inside a loop, scanf() with %d does not wait for the user input in case it received an invalid input previously?

Tags: c, scanf, stdin, input-buffer

I am using what `scanf() returns when it gets what is expects or when it doesn't. What happens is it gets stuck in the`while()` loop.

To my knowledge `test = scanf("%d", &testNum);` returns a 1 if it receives a number and a 0 if not.

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    while (1) {
        int testNum = 0;
        int test;
        printf("enter input");
        test = scanf("%d", &testNum);
        printf("%d", test);
        if (test == 0) {
            printf("please enter a number");
            testNum = 0;
        }
        else {
            printf("%d", testNum);
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is, upon encountring an *invalid* input, (a character, for example), the incorrect input is not *consumed*, it remains in the input buffer.

So, in the next loop, the same invalid input is again read by `scanf()`.

You need to clean up the buffer after identifying incorrect input. A very *simple* approach will be,

```
    if (test == 0) {
        printf("please enter a number");
        while (getchar() != '\n');  // clear the input buffer off invalid input
        testNum = 0;
    }
```

That said, either initialize `test`, or remove `printf("%d", test);`, as `test` being an automatic variable, unless initialized explicitly, contains indeterminate value. Attempt to use that can invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, just to be *nit-picky*, `return` is not a function, don't make it look like one. It's a staement, so `return 0;` is much more soothing to the eyes and much less confusing, anyway.

Comment: Note that `while (getchar() != '\n');` is an infinite loop on end-of-file condition.